# Read Linux terminal output from another terminal

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, python

Before, I would `rdp` into a device on the same terminal so I could read what is happening, whether the connection would open or not. I did it using try and except in python.

But now, I am using `gnome-terminal -x` to open another terminal. This way I can open multiple sessions of `rdp`.

Because of this, I am unable to make sure whether it has opened or not.

How do I know which ones opened and which ones failed? Before, if it couldn't log in because of wrong credentials, it would execute the except. Now, it doesn't execute the except section even if it fails log in. (now as in after `gnome-terminal -x`) What can I do now?

Here's my code:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
ip = "192.168.1.21"
password = "sam"
username = "root"
print "START!"
try:
      ans = subprocess.check_output(['gnome-terminal','-x','sudo','xfreerdp','-u',username,'-p',password, ip])
      os.system("y")



except:
      print("Cant Login!")
print "DONE!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use screen?

Use `$ screen -S "popeye"` to create the session with the name popeye

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>  to detach from the session.

Use `$ screen -x "popeye"` to re-attach to the session and check on things.

Then when you are done you just type `exit` from within the screen session and it quits the session.